# Настроить две сетевые карты в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, lan

Проблема в одновременной работе двух сетевых адаптеров.

```
ifconfig -a (ip я изменил)
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:97:5a:44:2b:ea  
      inet addr:5.5.5.154  Bcast:5.5.5.155  Mask:255.255.255.252
      inet6 addr: fe80::fe80:fe80:fe80:902b/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1630949 errors:0 dropped:937916 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:260081 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:145591068 (145.5 MB)  TX bytes:26712134 (26.7 MB)

enx00a0c6000000 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:a0:c6:00:00:00  
      inet addr:192.168.0.179  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::fe80:fe80:fe80:21d6/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:163156 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:213138 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:19446685 (19.4 MB)  TX bytes:46612878 (46.6 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:43287 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:43287 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:3770480 (3.7 MB)  TX bytes:3770480 (3.7 MB)
```

В данном случае все пакеты ходят через enx00a0c6000000. 
при отключении интерфейса enx00a0c6000000 через enp3s0. Но если enx00a0c6000000 включена, то происходит:

```
ping -I enp3s0 google.com
PING google.com (172.217.24.110) from 5.5.5.154 enp3s0: 56(84) bytes of data.

--- google.com ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 12295ms
```

Подскажите как и что настроить чтобы одновременно работали две сетевые карты?